# How to check if image exists in Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide, firebaseui

All in all I want to store and retrieve a profile picture for each user in Firebase. I am trying to retrieve the image from Firebase using FirebaseUI and Glide (as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui)).

It works perfectly for what I want to achieve, but I want to handle the case when the user didn't upload his own profile picture (when there is no picture in the Firebase storage). Sadly I am not able to find how to check if there is such a file in the Firebase storage. Does anyone have an idea how to check if there is a file `profile.jpg`

(in Firebase storage) in the following code?

```
StorageReference storageRef =  storageReference.child("profile.jpg");

ImageView imageView = profilePicture;
// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(context /* context */)
     .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
     .load(storageRef)
     .into(imageView);
```

Comment: When you say "handle the case when the user didn't upload his own profile picture" you want to call a specific method with business logic or only display a placeholder/error icon in profile `ImageView`?

Comment: I want to have a default profile picture for all the users that didn't upload their own. So by "handle" I mean that if there is no picture in the firebase storage I would like to show the default one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show default picture if there is no 'profile.jpg' on firebase, in newer v4 Glide, you can use RequestOptions, like this:

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions().error(R.drawable.default_avatar);
Glide.with(context /* context */)
         .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
         .load(storageRef)
         .apply(options)
         .into(imageView);
```

### Original answer for Glide v3

Use error method:

```
Glide.with(context /* context */)
     .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
     .load(storageRef)
     .error(R.drawable.default_avatar)
     .into(imageView);
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept the answer as well.

Comment: It don't work for me. I also tried ".error(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.some_other_vector))" and some other, still not working =[

Comment: @MikeYan for Glide v4 different code is needed, I updated answer